# yarn ios throws missing metro-config package error When running yarn ios the following error is shown

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When running `yarn ios` the following error is shown

> Missing package "metro-config" in the project. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.
> Error: Missing package "metro-config" in the project. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.
> at importMetroConfigFromProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/ExpoMetroConfig.ts:244:11)
> at getDefaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/ExpoMetroConfig.ts:70:23)
> at Object.loadAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/ExpoMetroConfig.ts:230:23)
> at runMetroDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/MetroDevServer.ts:67:45)
> at startDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startDevServerAsync.ts:62:55)
> at startAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startAsync.ts:74:41)

And after i was able to get the package i ran yarn ios again and i got this error:
metro-config tried to access metro-transform-worker, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: metro-transform-worker
Required by: metro-config@npm:0.66.2 (via /Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.yarn/cache/metro-config-npm-0.66.2-e011950457-9ea7732677.zip/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/)

Require stack:

- /Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.yarn/cache/metro-config-npm-0.66.2-e011950457-9ea7732677.zip/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js
- /Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.yarn/cache/metro-config-npm-0.66.2-e011950457-9ea7732677.zip/node_modules/metro-config/src/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
  Error: metro-config tried to access metro-transform-worker, but it isn't declared in its dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.

Required package: metro-transform-worker
Required by: metro-config@npm:0.66.2 (via /Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.yarn/cache/metro-config-npm-0.66.2-e011950457-9ea7732677.zip/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/)

Require stack:

- /Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.yarn/cache/metro-config-npm-0.66.2-e011950457-9ea7732677.zip/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js
- /Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.yarn/cache/metro-config-npm-0.66.2-e011950457-9ea7732677.zip/node_modules/metro-config/src/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/ExpoMetroConfig.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
  at Function.external_module_.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.pnp.cjs:22011:55)
  at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:98:19)
  at AsyncFunction.getDefaultValues (/Users/tolas/uber-eats-clone/.yarn/cache/metro-config-npm-0.66.2-e011950457-9ea7732677.zip/node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/index.js:140:28)
  at getDefaultConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/ExpoMetroConfig.ts:163:36)
  at Object.loadAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/ExpoMetroConfig.ts:230:23)
  at runMetroDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/MetroDevServer.ts:67:45)
  at startDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startDevServerAsync.ts:62:55)
  at startAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startAsync.ts:74:41)

Comment: Are you using expo? It seems that you are missing the `metro-config` package. You could add it using `yarn add metro-config`

Comment: Thanks i did it and i was able to get the metro-config package. but now i have another problem

Comment: could you add the other problem to your question?

Comment: I just did , Thanks

Comment: This is a similar issue, your project seems to have incomplete dependencies. If it's a new project I would recommend re-creating the project. An alternative would be to use `yarn add metro-transform-worker` to fix the second error